# Http Status 404 , Servlet not available

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, apache-axis

I am a newbie in creating webservices using AXIS 2 , Tomcat 6 , Java EE , eclipse (Juno).
There are 2 projects which i have in my workspace . One of it works fine and the other one 
does not work, so I am guessing there is some path to some library which is broken.

So when I run this not working project as run on server this page opens without any 
error

> localhost:8080/ProjectName/

It has 3 options Service, Validate, Administration. Then if I go in Services I get 404, validate gives me 500 and Administration gives me 404 error again.

**Web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>AdBoxWSProject</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

```
 <servlet>
  <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
  <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <display-name>SOAPMonitorService</display-name>
  <servlet-name>SOAPMonitorService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
       org.apache.axis2.soapmonitor.servlet.SOAPMonitorService
     </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>SOAPMonitorPort</param-name>
    <param-value>5001</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

SOAPMonitorService

```
   <url-pattern>/SOAPMonitor</url-pattern>
```

Axis Admin Servlet
    AdminServlet

```
   <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
     </web-app>
```

Also in my console window when i run the localhost i get this error :-

```
       Oct 30, 2012 2:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
       INFO: Servlet AxisAdminServlet is currently unavailable
```

Comment: You would want to provide more details to get an answer for this question. Could you provide the source of your jsp/html from where you click the various options, web.xml and if you are forwarding to the various options through a Servlet, provide the source of your Servlet as well.

Comment: i have added the web.xml but cant add source of my jsp/html as its a lot of code